# request authorization in OWIN middleware using also paramters from request

Tags: c#, .net, owin

I'm running an OWIN server with multiple controllers. I have an OWIN middleware which handles client certificate validation.

For my new controller I need an extra authorization step.

My controller POSTurl will be: `www.myUrl.com/api/newController/{service_id}`. The client will pass a client certificate alongside.
A client is only authorized to change specific `service_ids`. I need to verify if client X with certificate X is authorized to modify `service_id_1` passed in the URL parameters. I will have the `client_cert` -> `service_ids` mapping stored.

Which is the best way to do this for a single controller? I assume adding an Owin middleware won't be the proper way as all requests for all controllers will fly through it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution here is to check for proper access rights inside your controller action, or to create a custom authorization attribute, and implement your specific scenario inside.

for inline checking inside your action I think you know what to do, for the custom authorization attribute, here is what you need to do.

you will need to create a custom authorization attribute and override the `OnAuthorization` method, then inside it you will need to read the submitted certificate from the request parameters, and  make the check to either authorize or not-authorize the caller from the current action based on both the certificate and the requested serviceID.

an example of creating a custom authorization attribute can be found below:

```
public class CertificateAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{      
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // your custom logic here
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

My suggestion: because this is specific to this action method and not a general authorization problem, I would go for making the check inside your method, and if this needs to scale for more than one controller/action, then I may go for a custom authorization attribute.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I thought there would be a way to avoid having the logic at the very end (inside the controller itself). Also, another thing which feels wrong is that I already read the client certificate in the existing OWIN middleware and I would have to re-read it again from the request. But  seems there is no other way ...